# Centos start script for 'screen'?

Tags: centos, bash, gnu-screen, startup, centos5

I have a program that runs in the foreground so I run it via a 'screen'. Is there a good start/stop/restart template for 'screen'? I need it to pass the commands to the screen and create it if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're slightly confused.

All screen does is allow you to detach it from the current terminal, and reattach at a later date.

You can however, start a process within screen, detached.

`screen -d -m your_command_here`

Comment: I know, I am mainly looking for a basic template that would easy to modify to use screen. Along with how to create the screen if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "template for screen" but the `-R` option means "connect me to an existing screen or start a new one".  To be useful you'll want something like `screen -d -R -S myscreen`.  The -d option will detach it if it was already attached somewhere else, and "-S myscreen" will name your screen session so future `screen -d -R -S myscreen` commands will know which screen you're talking about.

Unfortunately, -d -R -S can't be used with -d -m, so you can't say "start a screen named myscreen in detached mode unless there's already a screen named myscreen".  Once it's started, you'll have to use the ctrl-a ctrl-d command to detach it if you don't want it running in the foreground.

Anything after the options will be executed as a command in a new screen only, so you can execute `screen -d -R -S myscreen /some/program` to:
1) If a screen named myscreen exists, detach it from wherever it is and reattach it here
2) If the screen does not exist, create it and execute `/some/program` in it.

Note that if you run a command in screen, when that command exits so will screen.

Comment: I need a basic easy to edit start/stop/restart init.d script.